# In Flex 3 Textarea, how to implement Text Search functionality

Tags: flex3, search-engine, replace

I wish to implement 'find...' functionality on the text present in mx:TextArea control. I could find the word using indexOf() function. I am finding difficult to:

1. highlight correct word
2. continue search using shortcut key say Ctrl+f (or F3)
3. wrap search functionality

Please let me know a way to overcome these issues?

Answer (score 0):

The text to find can be highlighted using `textArea.setSelection()`. For reference see [this link](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/04/25/setting-text-selection-on-a-textarea-control-in-flex/)